# npm error missing script: build (Set up CI with Azure Pipelines)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure DevOps from Microsoft and try to build a pipeline. When I run it than the following error shows up (note that I am using Nodejs):

```
2019-02-27T14:51:52.8760703Z ##[section]Starting: npm install and build
2019-02-27T14:51:52.8763347Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-27T14:51:52.8763405Z Task         : Command Line
2019-02-27T14:51:52.8763440Z Description  : Run a command line script using cmd.exe on Windows and bash on macOS and Linux.
2019-02-27T14:51:52.8763490Z Version      : 2.146.1
2019-02-27T14:51:52.8763523Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-02-27T14:51:52.8763557Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
2019-02-27T14:51:52.8763604Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-27T14:51:53.0258171Z Generating script.
2019-02-27T14:51:53.0326177Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/10b6fcd3-847a-4422-bb84-ba6e0b8ca7cb.sh
2019-02-27T14:51:54.3278066Z npm WARN holzlauf@1.0.0 No description
2019-02-27T14:51:54.3278893Z npm WARN holzlauf@1.0.0 No repository field.
2019-02-27T14:51:54.3279186Z 
2019-02-27T14:51:54.5749996Z audited 175 packages in 1.032s
2019-02-27T14:51:54.5757001Z found 0 vulnerabilities
2019-02-27T14:51:54.5757413Z 
2019-02-27T14:51:54.8302910Z npm ERR! missing script: build
2019-02-27T14:51:55.4914767Z 
2019-02-27T14:51:55.4916102Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-02-27T14:51:55.4916931Z npm ERR!     /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2019-02-27T14_51_54_831Z-debug.log
2019-02-27T14:51:55.5084373Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2019-02-27T14:51:55.5117395Z ##[section]Finishing: npm install and build
```

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "holzlauf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.conf.js",
    "deploy": "npm run build && gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "applicationinsights": "^1.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent or Private agent? can you share your build pipeline?

Comment: Did you ever find out the issue?

Comment: If you rerun the pipeline manually, it can use previous code state, maybe that's the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

It means in your “package.json” (in the folder in which you run “npm run build”), there’s NO “build” script

```
{ 
 "name": "Example Application", 
 "version": "1.0.0", 
 "description": "", 
 "main": "index.js", 
 "scripts": { 
    "build": "echo 'build script executed'" 
 }, 
 "author": "", 
 "license": "" 
}
```

Reference:
https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-you-get-the-NPM-error-missing-script-build